# Apache 2.2 phpinfo() Configuration File (php.ini) Path doesn't match httpd.conf

Tags: apache, php, httpd.conf

I am trying to set up Apache to work with PHP. It seems to be working because I can run a file index.php from my "example" directory which is within htdocs in Apache. However, when I look at the Configuration File (php.ini) Path on the phpinfo() screen it does not match what I have in httpd.conf. Also, my modules that are turned on within my php.ini file are not set to enabled.

So I think it is not getting my php.ini. On the phpinfo() screen it says the Path is C:\Windows.

In my httpd file in the conf directory of Apache I have this:

```
.
.
.
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule php5_module C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

All of these files exist. However this is not even a php.ini at C:\Windows.

You may say that maybe my httpd.conf file isn't being read. However, if I change the php5_module line to something like

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/php/incorect.dll
```

Apache fails to start up. So this is being read. Just my php.ini isn't being read. Why? Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** Also want to mention, on the phpinfo() screen,
Loaded Configuration File is displaying as (none). Not sure what this is even talking about, but just some more insight to those of you who do.

Oh, and PHP version is 5.4.6.

**EDIT 2:** 
Windows Version: Windows 7 Professional
Service Pack: Service Pack 1

Comment: Have you added "C:/php/" to your PATH?

Comment: Try. You can do it from `cmd`: set PATH="%PATH%;C:\php"

Comment: I just tried that, and looked at my Path variable in environment variables, and what I put wasn't added. My System Variable for Path is  not spelled PATH though, it's Path, is that the right one?

Comment: Yes, it could be `Path`. Check it in your control panel: `System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables` (win7). You can add user variable "Path" (or "PATH") or system variable with the same name, that doesn't matters.

Comment: Then yes, it's in there and Apache still is not picking it up.

Comment: What if you'll temporarily rename your `php.ini` from `C:\php` to `php.ini.inactive` (or move it to another directory)? Will your Apache start?

Comment: Yes it still starts, I don't understand how though.

Comment: Okay, please show your output of `php -i |grep "php.ini"` (type it in cmd)

Comment: I don't have the grep command on my system, it says not recognized.

Comment: Do your apache logs show any issues with PHPIniDir?  You might try `PHPIniDir "C:\php\"`?

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that, and no there's nothing mentioned about it in the error log file.

Comment: I've checked it on my system, in php_info() there are two rows: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` = `C:\Windows` and `Loaded Configuration File` = `C:\Php5\php.ini` It works for me fine.

Comment: I do notice when I restart apache I am seeing this message in the logs:
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.146 for ServerName

Comment: As to your message in logs - that's not connected with issue, just add `ServerName localhost` in your `httpd.conf` and it will disappear. :)

Comment: Have you added the php handler as well?

Comment: Well the problem with mine though is, my php.ini file isn't in c:\Windows. I think if I put it there it might work correctly, but I'd like to have it in C:\php. EDIT: No, I was wrong, it's not even picking up my modules that I'v enabled when I move it to C:\Windows.

Comment: Why you're so sure your `php.ini` doesn't works?

Comment: PHP Handler ernie? I'm sure it doesn't work because I have turned on modules and they are not showing up in the phpinfo() screen.

Comment: I think the problem is I downloaded a VC9 version of PHP? Apache can only use VC6, correct? Problem is, I can't find a VC6 version of PHP for 64 bit Windows. Anyone can help me with this? .mis installer preferable, no idea how to do it without.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

To:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Load module:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Add PHP handler:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Update directory index (optionally):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Include "c:\php" to the end of your `Path` variable.

Comment: It's strange. Have you restarted `httpd` after that? Try to reboot your system as well.

Comment: Restart httpd? I restart Apache. I can try a system reboot too though.

Comment: Yes, `httpd` that's your Apache HTTP Server. How you installed Apache and how you start it? As a Windows service or by running binary?

Comment: I start it as a Windows Service. Installed it using the .msi installer or whatever you call it. I am on my old comp right now my compi I'm having these problems on is going through some stupid Windows updates right now upon restarting, but I checked my php.ini here with phpinfo() and it IS suppose to actually be C:\Windows for Configuration File path, but the other one, the one that is showing (none) for me SHOULD say C:/php/php.ini. So that's the problem I'm at now.

And the system restart didn't help the problem, still (none) for Loaded Configuration file.

Comment: Could you please tell your Windows version and service pack as well? Include all that information in your question.

Comment: Wait, AddHandler, I had AddType with that but not AddHandler, are they the same thing? Well I added it and didn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: you saved my life, removing the "/" from the PHPIniDir fixed the problem on my server, thank you for this, i really really appreciate

Comment: you saved my life [2], I needed to add the php.exe directory to the environment PATH

Comment: what if i'm using php's 7.4 version should php5_modules be php7_modules in LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll".

Comment: I've been hunting high and low for my PHP extensions not getting loaded with Apache, but CLI worked fine. It was all because PHPIniDir was missing from my httpd.conf, argh what a headache and many hours lost just because of this one line that should have a default value within PHP. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED - Can't be forward slashes, have to be back. took

```
PHPIniDir "C:\srv\php5_4_8\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to install it properly, on IIS 7:

Set IIS to allow 32-bits if you are on 64-bits

cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1

Set enviroment variables

PATH to, say, C:\php\

PHPRC to, that same dir

Go to Web Service Extensions: Add a new extension...

Name it for example php, and point it to the php5isapi.dll.

Set status to Allowed.

Right click Web Sites:

On the tab, ISAPI Filters, name it for example php, and point it to the php5isapi.dll

Then go to Home directory tab:

Click Configuration

On Mappings, click add:

Executable would be: php5isapi.dll
Extension to: .php

Click OK, then OK.

Then on the tab Documents click Add:

and add there what you want to load as default, say index.php

Then stop, and start IIS.

This worked for me on a Windows 2003 Server, and WinXP 64.

I hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

My System: `Windows with apache 2.2, php 5.3`

Symptoms:
`PDO drivers not found.`

What I found:
phpinfo() showed that the php.ini file was `"C:\Windows"` even though I expected it to be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\"` as specified in my `httpd.conf` file in `apache\conf`

Problem was with the `PHPIniDir` string in `httpd.conf` so the `php.ini` file I intended to use was not found.

FAILED:

```
PHPIniDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\"
```

WORKED:

```
PHPIniDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP"
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP"
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/"
```

**NOTICE:** the extra "\" in the FAILED case. Remove it, save the conf file, and restart apache. Now phpinfo should show the php.ini file as coming from "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP" and the PDO drivers had been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same issue.

In my case, the problem was that I had saved the php.ini file as a text file. As soon as I converted the text file to "All Files" in notepad and gave it the ".ini" extension, it became a "Configuration Settings File" and it worked.

(Working on Windows)

Answer (score -1):

Since I am running Windows 7 (Apache 2.2 & PHP 5.2.17 & MySQL 5.0.51a), the syntax in the file "httpd.conf" (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf) was very sensitive to slashes. I needed to change from

`PHPIniDir 'c:\PHP'`

to

`PHPIniDir 'c:\PHP'`

**Pay the attention that the last slash disturbed everything!**

Comment: Umm - they're both the same